How do I restart the docker daemon for Rancher from a Mac?
I'm moving across from Docker to Rancher.
https://rancherdesktop.io
One challenge I get is when I get an error with docker compose the daemon just seems to stop. The current way I restart is to restart the Rancher application. It strikes me that I ought to be able to do this from the command line.
I found the following regarding Docker itself, but not particularly useful for Rancher:
How do I restart Docker for Mac from the terminal?

I don't think this option is available at the moment. What I usually do is Quit Rancher Desktop and reopen.
